# How to left align the equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am using below equation in my document. By default, it is getting aligned at the center. I want to left-align the equation -- *only this equation, not all equations in the document*. Can anybody tell me how it can be done?

```
\begin{equation}
d_j =
  \begin{cases}
    newval_i,  & \quad i = j\\
    randval_k, & \quad k = j\\
    bestval_j, & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Should all equations be left-aligned, or just this one?

Comment: unrelated to alignment but that should be `\mathit{newval}_i` and similarly the other names, never use the default math italic for multi-letter words.

Comment: @Mico only this  one

Comment: @Atinesh - The fact that you only wish to left-align a single equation is very important, and unfortunately it's something that wasn't mentioned in your posting. It's not too late, though, to edit your posting and to clarify what it is you're trying to achieve. Go ahead.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I have already gone through that post, It didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I've edited and "reopened" this posting. In the edit, I provided some (apparently much needed) emphasis on the fact that the OP wishes to left-align only one particular equation, not all equations in the document. Hence, the suggestion to use set the `fleqn` option isn't applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that nesting your equations in a `fleqn` environment (from `nccmath`). This environment accepts an optional argument for the distance from the left margin ( `0 pt` by default):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
d_j =
  \begin{cases}
    \text{newval}_i, & \quad i = j\\
    \text{randval}_k, & \quad k = j\\
    \text{bestval}_j, & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{fleqn}
\noindent\texttt{With fleqn: }
\begin{equation}
d_j =
  \begin{cases}
    \text{newval}_i, & \quad i = j\\
    \text{randval}_k, & \quad k = j\\
    \text{bestval}_j, & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\begin{fleqn}[3em]
\noindent\texttt{With fleqn and optional argument [3em]: }
\begin{equation}
d_j =
  \begin{cases}
    \text{newval}_i, & \quad i = j\\
    \text{randval}_k, & \quad k = j\\
    \text{bestval}_j, & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice use of the `nccmath` package!

Comment: Thanks, @Mico. The package has many useful little things – the main point for me being medium-sized maths, intermediate between display style and text style for fractions, integrals, matrices and so on.